# Docker Ruby Bundler not installing

Tags: ruby, docker, dockerfile, bundler

My Dockerfile looks like below:

```
FROM ruby:2.5-alpine

RUN apk update add --no-cache build-base nodejs postgresql-dev

RUN mkdir /my-app
WORKDIR /my-app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install --binstubs

COPY . .

CMD puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Now when I try to create an image, it gives following error:

```
You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install --binstubs' returned a non-zero code: 20
```

The bundler version Gemfile.lock using is 2.1.4.
I did tried adding following line to Dockerfile:

```
RUN gem update --system
RUN gem install bundler -v 2.1.4
```

In that case, I get following error:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (= 2.1.4), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 system. Anyone had faced this issue before? Any help appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where did you add this install bundler line? since when I do it it works (never the less I get warnigs/errors for --binstubs), Besides that if I add "RUN gem update --system && gem install bundler && bundle --version" It installs 2.1.4, what is the version you get when you do not specify a version?

Comment: I add install bundler line after WORKDIR line. I have specified bundler version 2.1.4 but it never get installed. It throws error at `RUN gem update --system`

Answer (score 2):

```
FROM ruby:2.5-alpine

RUN apk update add --no-cache build-base nodejs postgresql-dev

RUN mkdir /my-app
WORKDIR /my-app

RUN gem update --system
RUN gem install bundler -v 2.1.4
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install --binstubs

COPY . .

CMD puma -C config/puma.rb
```

So, installing bundler was fine but due IPV6 of rubygems.org is still broken and create issue while fetching inside docker. So, i ran the command using host network.

```
docker image build --network=host -t my-app .
```

And this issue was resolved.

Thanks for taking time.

Comment: Using `--network=host` worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I need to create an answer since I can not post this all into a comment. I realize that this is not a solution for you.

If I use this setup, It runs without an error. Can you please look where it differs from your setup and tests? (please also add this to the question)

**dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.5-alpine

RUN apk update add --no-cache build-base nodejs postgresql-dev

RUN mkdir /my-app
WORKDIR /my-app

RUN gem update --system && gem install bundler && bundle --version 
# installs bundler 2.1.4

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install

COPY . .

CMD /bin/sh
```

**Gemfile**

```
ruby '2.5.8'
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'flay'
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    erubis (2.7.0)
    flay (2.12.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      path_expander (~> 1.0)
      ruby_parser (~> 3.0)
      sexp_processor (~> 4.0)
    path_expander (1.0.3)
    ruby_parser (3.13.1)
      sexp_processor (~> 4.9)
    sexp_processor (4.12.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  flay

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.5.8p224

BUNDLED WITH
   2.1.4
```

Build and started with:

```
docker build . --no-cache -t foobar
docker run --it foobar
```